# Getting the drop-down menu selected item and using it in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following drop-down list that fetches a list coalitions from the database (this list is populated as expected)

```
<form style = "display: inline-block;" >
        <select class="form-control" name ="coalition_select" onchange = "showCandidates(this.value)" method="GET">
            <option id = "coalition_id" value="coalition">Coalitions</option>
                <?php 
                    include_once 'connection.php';
                    $sql_coalition = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT coalition FROM candidates");
                    while ($row = $sql_coalition->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<option value=\"coalition\">" . $row['coalition'] . "</option>";
                    }
                ?>
        </select> 
</form>
```

The problem begins here. Here I'm trying to first get the selected value (which is on of the coalitions) from the drop-down list and second use the value to display users with similar coalition attribute.

here is the script to get the value from the drop-down:

```
<script>
    function showCandidates (str) {
        if (str.length == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/admin.users.list.inc.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

and here is the admin.users.list.inc.php file

```
<body>
    <?php
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','voting');
        if (!$conn) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conn,"osako_Voting");
        $sql="SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE coalition = '".$q."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        echo "<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Coalition</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['coalition'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
</body>
```

The problem seem to be that I'm unable to set the variable `$q` so that it captures the selected value. right now as it is set it seems to capture the index instead of the value itself. How can this be correctly done? If it is of any help, I'm using this tutorial as a guideline
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

IN SUMMERY:
If we have a drop-down list that has been populated dynamically using php script. How can be get the selected value using ajax and use the said value in another php script.

Thanks

Comment: Unclear question, in my opinion. Please made it easy to understand and clear "what is your question"

Comment: @vietnguyen09 If we have a drop-down list that has been populated dynamically using php script. How can be get the selected value using ajax and use the said value in another php script

Comment: So you just want to get the `selected value` in `select box` with javascript?

Comment: Why are you using `method='get'` in your `select` tag?

Comment: @vietnguyen09 yes and then use the value in another php file where I display the user info in a table

Comment: @ankit my mistake I took it away. no changes

Comment: Also consider using `$.ajax()` of jQuery it will save you time and effort and handle cross-browsers issues for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is in this row:

```
echo "<option value=\"coalition\">" . $row['coalition'] . "</option>";
```

You're passing the select value to showCandidates(), to be passed via AJAX but you're setting the option value to be always static "coalition" and not the dynamic values you're fetching from DB.
Maybe you should change the row to

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $row['coalition'] . "\">" . $row['coalition'] . "</option>";
```

Answer (score 2):

your not setting `value` to `value attribute` . your just setting constant string for all option values  `coalition`

```
while ($row = $sql_coalition->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<option value=\"$row['coalition']\">" . $row['coalition'] . "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have accepted an answer but i am puzzled as to this; 
in your function you have this

`document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";`

But you don't have any form element with the id `"txtHint"`

So what element is being sort with that ID?